# Turning Table Sideways

Tags: tables, landscape

I am wondering how I would turn this table sideways, as all of the columns cannot fit when its on portrait. The table needs to be a 5X5. Thanks for the help.

```
\begin{table}{11r11}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!} 
\hline
long name & long name & long name & long name
\\hline
$long name$ & ## \\
$long name$ & ## \\
$long name$ & ## \\
$long name$ & ## \\
$long name$ & ## \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{$^{a}$Table note text here.}
enter code here
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You could either use the sidewaystable from the rotating package or totate the whole page using the landscape environment from pdflscape or lscape.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use resizebox on a table as this will inevitably lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout the document. Please also be aware that your code currently contains some syntax errors. \begin{tabular} is missing and table usually does not accept a mandatory argument.

Comment: You not provide any information about your document . Is it one column document (if it is, you shoed table code fragment not need to be rotated), if it is two column document it my help to use `table*` float. Is it allowed to have multiline text in cells? Please, be so kind and extend your code fragment to complete small compilable document, which reproduce your problem and with it make your question clear.

Comment: BTW, if my answer helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept it by clicking on the checkmark symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I might do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \afterpage{%
        \clearpage%
        \begin{landscape}
            \begin{table}[p]
                \centering
                \begin{threeparttable}[h]
                    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
                        \toprule
                        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{long name} \\
                        \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
                        long name & long name & long name & long name& long name\\
                    \midrule
                        long name\tnote1 & long name & long name & long name& long name\\
                        long name\tnote\textdagger & long name & long name & long name& long name\\
                        long name & long name & long name & long name& long name\\
                        long name & long name & long name & long name& long name\\
                        long name & long name & long name & long name& long name\\
                    \bottomrule
                    \end{tabular}
                    \begin{tablenotes}
                        \item[1] A table note.
                        \item[\textdagger] Another table note.
                    \end{tablenotes}
                \end{threeparttable}
            \end{table}
        \end{landscape}
    }
    \par
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

This uses the `pdflscape` package and the `landscape` environment to rotate the page, as suggested by @leandriis. The `afterpage` package is used to put the (floating) table on its own page.

I've also used the `booktabs` package (which provides `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` and `\cmidrule`) to make the table look nicer, and the `threeparttable` package (which provides `\tnote` and the `tablenotes` environment etc.) to add footnotes to the table.

The `lipsum` package is just used to generate the surrounding text. Hope this helps!